# Getting relative units value

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to know how to get a relative units value
example, I have an element with width 80% of its viewport's width, and I would like to get the value of the width with javascript

```js
console.log(Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('maxwidth').style.width));
```

```html
<div id="maxwidth" style="width: 80vw;"></div>
```

Comment: it's working fine ... maybe in your real code you are not setting this value inline ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Relative Width

You should calculate relative width, width in percentage, of an element yourself. Use this function to do so.

```js
function getRelativeWidth(element) {
  var offsetParent = element.offsetParent || element;
  return ((element.offsetWidth / offsetParent.offsetWidth) * 100).toFixed(3) + '%';
}

var element = document.getElementById('maxwidth')
console.log(getRelativeWidth(element))
```

```html
<div id="maxwidth" style="width: 80vw;"></div>
```

---

#### [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)

Use this function to get the width of an element including its border and padding.

```js
function getOffsetHeight(element) {
  return element.offsetWidth
}

var element = document.getElementById('maxwidth')
console.log(getOffsetHeight(element))
```

```html
<div id="maxwidth" style="width: 80vw;"></div>
```

---

#### [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)

Use this function to get the width of a none inline element excluding its border and margin but including its padding.

```js
function getClientWidth(element){
    return element.clientWidth
}

var element = document.getElementById('maxwidth')
console.log(getClientWidth(element))
```

```html
<div id="maxwidth" style="width: 80vw;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('maxwidth').style.width);
```

with

```
Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('maxwidth').clientWidth);
```

```js
console.log(Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('maxwidth').clientWidth));
```

```html
<div id="maxwidth" style="width: 80vw;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `vw` value in pixel

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth * vw / 100
```

e.g. if your viewport is `400px` wide and your element is `80vw` then it's actually

```
400 * 80vw / 100 = 320px
```

and it should be recalculated at every `resize` event of the window.

---

Otherwise you can use `.getComputedStyle()`

```
let d   = document.querySelector('div'),
    gcs = window.getComputedStyle(d, null);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    let w = gcs.getPropertyValue("width");
    d.textContent = "current width: " + w;  
});
```

> [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeXovX)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get element's width in *non-relative* units, you can simply use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) like this:

```
const style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("maxwidth"), null);
// style.width is your element's width expressed in pixels
```